# VBA code to print every worksheet in workbook as legal size

Tags: excel, vba

I tried the following code but it doesn't seem to work - can someone help me debug?

```
Sub printt()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("link to file")

For Each ws In wb
ws.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperLegal
Next

For Each ws In wb
ws.PrintOut
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: *but it doesn't seem to work* ... Not helpful. What is the error message?

Comment: 'object doesnt support this property or method'

Comment: Please! On what line? We cannot read your mind!

Comment: Your `For Each` loop needs to reference `wb.Worksheets` not just `wb`...

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub printt()

Dim wb As Workbook 
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("link to file")

For Each ws In wb.worksheets
     ws.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperLegal 
     ws.PrintOut
Next ws




End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this code and I get an error that says 'method 'printout' of object 'worksheet' failed